# Prove String is referene type in C#

Tags: c#-2.0

While I know string is reference type, but i could now prove it. because if I take variable test1 as string and assign some value then take other variable naming test2 and assign test2 with test1 variable. so if string is reference type then address of variable test1 will be assign to variable test2. so if i assign some value in tet2 variable which will be reflected in variable test1, but it's not happened.

other one example is if we pass two string variable in function and change value in this function will reflect in calling function, but it's not happen, please see example:-
and give me example by which i can prove that string is reference type. but behavior is different in both case class object and string variable please see again this example. I have edited

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string test1 = string.Empty;
        string test2;

        String test3 = new String(new char[10]);

        test1 = "hemant";
        test2 = test1;


        test2 = "Soni";

        //becuase if string is reference type then after asign value "soni"
        // in test2, test1 also show value "soni" instead of value "hemant"

        Console.WriteLine("test1:" + test1); // but displaying "hemant", while shoul display "soni"
        Console.WriteLine("test2:" + test2); // while displaying "soni"

        test3 = "soni";

        // if string is reference type then after calling this function
        //value of variables test1 and test3 should be changed.
        testfn(test1, test3);
        Console.WriteLine("test1:" + test1);// but stile displaying "hemant" instead of "hemant New"
        Console.WriteLine("test3:" + test3);// but stile displaying "soni" instead of "soni New"

        // should be true, because if string reference type then address of both variable should be same.
        bool check = test1 == test2;

        clsTest obj = new clsTest();
        obj.x1 = "Hemant";
        obj.x2 = "Soni";

        Console.WriteLine("obj.x1:" + obj.x1); //"Hemant";
        Console.WriteLine("obj.x2:" + obj.x2);//"Soni";
        callFn(obj);
        //after calling  value has been changed of this object, but in string type its not happed like this
        Console.WriteLine("obj.x1:" + obj.x1); //"Hemant New";
        Console.WriteLine("obj.x2:" + obj.x2);//"Soni New";

        
    }
     public class clsTest
    {
        public string x1;
        public string x2;
    }

    void callFn(clsTest obj)
    {
        obj.x1 = "Hemant New";
        obj.x2 = "Soni New";
    }
    void testfn(string x, String y)
    {
        x = "Hemant New";
        y = "Soni New";
    }
```

Comment: You're confusing reference assignment and mutation.  `String` is immutable.

Comment: And strings can be interned as well which might add to the confusion in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String is a reference type but it is also immutable. Meaning, you cannot change the value of the string object, only replace it with a reference to another string. Thus when you pass the string into the function and you are assigning the parameter you are only changing the reference of the parameter of `x` not changing the value at x. To change the reference at `x` you must use the ref or out keyword on the parameter. This is also true of any kind of object in C#.

```
class Example {
    public string Value;
}

void Foo(Example x, ref Example y) {
  x.Value = "mutated"; // mutating the reference
  x = new Example { Value = "new reference" }; // only changes local variable

  y.Value = "mutated"; // mutating the reference
  y = new Example { Value = "new reference" }; // changes the references y is pointing to
}


var x = new Example { Value = "x" };
var y = new Example { Value = "y" };
Foo(x, ref y);

Console.WriteLine(x.Value); // mutated
Console.WriteLine(y.Value); // new reference
```

But since string is immutable (it cannot be mutated) the only way to change values passed in as parameters is by using the ref or out keywords.

Comment: But behaviour is different in both case, class object and string variable, please see example:

Comment: But Behaviour is different in both case class object and string , please see above example, i have edited with class object

Comment: Yeah that's what I said, because you're mutating the value being pointed to by the object reference. But you can't do that to a string. Simply changing the reference won't change the values. For example change the function to this and try again: 

`void callFn(clsTest obj) { obj = new clsTest { x1 = "new", x2 = "new" }; }`

You'll notice that it doesn't change the values now in that case. Now for the sting case, try this:

`testFn(string x, string y) { x[0] = 'n'; x[1] = 'e'; x[2] = 'w'; }`

This would be mutating the string, but notice that it is not allowed and results in compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `ref` keyword to testfn.

```
void testfn(ref string x, ref String y)
```

This will reference the object directly.

[MSDN ref page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)